# Is it right to use LINQ queries in ASP MVC views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

I've developed a website which its index page has lots of queries I write them as some LINQ codes in the view (between HTMLs).
Load time of the index page of the website is very slow!

Does it related to this way of querying?

If yes, please tell me about the exact process of the rendering a requested page by ASP.MVC

I think that ASP.Net or C# coding in the view degrades the performance and increase the load time of the web page.

Comment: The controller retrieves all the data and when finished it passes the data to the view to render it. The view has nothing to do with the query part

Comment: @SirRufo - Not all people design it like that though.

Comment: While this question may ask about code in place without showing it, it has enough information to answer with fact and without writing a book. This situation highlighted is commonly misunderstood, in my opinion. I do not think it should be closed.

Comment: @TravisJ The question need rewording. Currently, the main question is whether having LINQ in the view is causing slow load times. Although I don't have time to check right now, I would imagine that a question about how to correctly structure an ASP MVC application has already been asked.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde - This question is scoped only to executing code in the view. There are several aspects involved that may also broadly apply to structuring an entire mvc application, but since the question is narrowly scoped to the view, there isn't all that much to cover.

Comment: paste in a code example.

Comment: I offer you guys to have some abstract thinking ability instead of closing question because you can not understand it. The question domain is obvious! I've queried the DB in the view using LINQ but as you may now the normal way is to query in the controller. I had a question that if this style of coding in ASP MVC affects the load time of the page or not? Now, I my problem is solved and if you mind it you can open this question so that I can write my correct answer,

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the thing with rendering an html page from asp.net mvc: **all that gets rendered is the result of a string**. If you view a page's source then that is the string you will see.

The string itself comes from writing to the response stream. Building the string is where the issue of performance comes in to play.

There are three main aspects of performance to consider:

- Time Complexity: How long is the computation (if any exists) taking to complete based on the size of data it needs to act on?
- Spacial Complexity: How much memory is being used by the computation (if any exists), and is that amount available?
- Bandwidth: How long is it taking to gather the data?

Each one of these aspects is at play anywhere that c# code is executing. Even in a view, *if c# code is present, it is executed prior to the string being written to the response*.

There are several ways that your query could impact performance from the view.

- If the view opens a connection to the database, then the efficiency of the query and also the size of the data returned will effect performance. Either by taking a long time to execute due to complexity, or by downloading a large amount of data from the database. To remedy this, it is important to:

  - limit the amount of data being taken either by using a projection (`.Select()`)
  - use a metric such as a date range to limit the group of data
  - ensure that the data is not being lazy loaded (in other words, make sure that only *one* round trip to the database takes place instead of several)
- If the view contains linq code which contains several nested calls or recursion, then this could cause a large amount of computation time. To remedy this, it is important to break the computation apart either by using a more efficient approach, advanced processing techniques, caching, or a smaller data window.
- If the view contains linq code which is generating a large amount of html, then that will all be written to the response stream. A large amount of html will cause the page to load slowly because it is taking a long time to download, and then again it will be slow as a result of needing to render all of that html. To remedy this, avoid using excessive amounts of razor code to generate html in your view.

The easiest way to determine which of these problems you are encountering is to check the page load time, versus the page rendering time, as well as the page size. The size is easy enough to check in the network tab of chrome.